# A problem in order details return

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to return more details about order, customer, product and shipping after order placement so can handle my own custom API. I have this code in `successAction` method in :
app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnePageController.php

```
public function successAction()
    {
        $session = $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout();
        if (!$session->getLastSuccessQuoteId()) {
            $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
            return;
        }

        $lastQuoteId = $session->getLastQuoteId();
        $lastOrderId = $session->getLastOrderId();
        $lastRecurringProfiles = $session->getLastRecurringProfileIds();
        if (!$lastQuoteId || (!$lastOrderId && empty($lastRecurringProfiles))) {
            $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
            return;
        }

// start

        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId());


        $customerID = $order['customer_id'];
        $customerFirstName = $order['customer_firstname'];
        $customerLastName = $order['customer_lastname'];
        $customerEmail = $order['customer_email'];
        $orderID = $order->getId();
        $shippingAddressID = $order['shipping_address_id'];

        foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {

            $orders['orders']['items'][] = array(

                'productID'           => $item->getProductId(),
                'sku'                 => $item->getSku(),
                'orderedQty'          => $item->getQtyOrdered(),

            );

       echo "Product ID: ".  $item->getProductId()."<br/>";

       //send my api

        }    

  //end      

        $session->clear();
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('checkout/session');
        Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_onepage_controller_success_action', array('order_ids' => array($lastOrderId)));
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
```

The problem is: there are another products returned. For more clear when I choose one product and do checkout then place order, I see my product and another product returned. how to prevent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use magento event like "**checkout_onepage_controller_success_action**" which will be called after successfull order.
where you can write a method to call api using **soap/Rest**.You can get all the information from event object.

1. Register your module in app/etc/modules/Magentotutorial_Exportorder.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config>
       <modules>
           <Magentotutorial_Exportorder>
               <active>true</active>
               <codePool>local</codePool>
           </Magentotutorial_Exportorder>
       </modules>
   </config>
   ```
2. Place in **app/code/local/Magentotutorial/Exportorder/etc/config.xml**

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config>    
       <modules>
           <Magentotutorial_Exportorder>
               <version>1.0.0.0.1</version>
           </Magentotutorial_Exportorder>
       </modules>

       <frontend> <!-- observer event will only be executed on the frontend -->
           <events>        
               <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
                   <observers>
                       <Magentotutorial_Exportorder_Model_Observer>
                           <type>singleton</type>
                           <class>Magentotutorial_Exportorder_Model_Observer</class>
                           <method>callApi</method>
                       </Magentotutorial_Exportorder_Model_Observer>
                   </observers>
               </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>

           </events>
       </frontend>

       <global>
           <models>
               <exportorder>
                   <class>Magentotutorial_Exportorder_Model</class>
               </exportorder>
           </models>
           <helpers>
               <exportorder>
                   <class>Magentotutorial_Exportorder_Model</class>
               </exportorder>
           </helpers>
       </global>

   </config>
   ```
3. Placing app/code/local/Magentotutorial/Exportorder/Observer.php, in class **Magentotutorial_Exportorder_Model_Observer**, write method

   class Magentotutorial_Exportorder_Model_Observer {

   ```
   public function callApi(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {

           $orderIds = $observer->getData('order_ids');
           $orderId = current($orderIds);

           //get all info from order
           $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);

           //call your api

           Mage::log($order , null, 'custom_order.log');

       }
   }
   ```